# I have developed http://livexcellence.com site using react.js. The link will breack after we refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[enter link description here](http://livexcellence.com)

When I navigate to different to different pages after the initial load, the app works perfectly fine. But When I refresh the same URL or copy and paste the same URl the page fails to load.

The problem is when I copy the same URl and open in another page, or refresh the same URl, the link will not work?

example: http://livexcellence.com/readytomove will not work if you try to open the link directly. Although the above link is with the websiteitself

Comment: do you have access to the web server? Since it's an SPA, and the name after the slash doesn't actually represent a real page, you will need to configure your web server to handle this.

Comment: No, I do not have a web server. I actually hosted it on godaddy. Can you please help a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to access the correct page on http://livexcellence.com/#readytomove. Since you are using react routing regardless of you hosting the page